# What is the best way to convert mainframe signed characters to corresponding integer values in Java

Tags: java, str-replace

I have a scenario where characters like below will be coming in the fixed length file

{ABCDEFGHI = This set of characters represents positive numbers 0123456789 respectively

}JKLMNOPQR = This set of characters represents negative numbers 0123456789 respectively

I need to convert them into corresponding number 0123456789(positive and negative) using java.
for example:

45{ should be converted to  450 (as '{' represents positive '0' )

45A should be converted to  451 (as 'A' represents positive '1' )

45B should be converted to  452 (as 'A' represents positive '2' )

45} should be converted to  -450 (as '}' represents negative '0' )

45J should be converted to  -451 (as 'J' represents negative '1' )

45K should be converted to  -452 (as 'K' represents negative '2' )

I am not that good in java so I am using below code to first replace the string containing above mentioned character with the corresponding number using replace function. I know there must be a better way to do that.Can any please suggest me on this.Many thanks in advance.

```
public static String replaceChar(String str) {
        if (str.contains("{")) {
            str =  str.replace("{", "0");
        }   
        if (str.contains("A")) {
            str =  str.replace("A", "1");
        }
        if (str.contains("B")) {
            str =  str.replace("B", "2");
        }
        if (str.contains("C")) {
            str =  str.replace("C", "3");
        }
        if (str.contains("D")) {
            str =  str.replace("D", "4");
        }
        if (str.contains("E")) {
            str =  str.replace("E", "5");
        }
        if (str.contains("F")) {
            str =  str.replace("F", "6");
        }
        if (str.contains("G")) {
            str =  str.replace("G", "7");
        }
        if (str.contains("H")) {
            str =  str.replace("H", "8");
        }
        if (str.contains("I")) {
            str =  str.replace("I", "9");
        }
        if (str.contains("J")) {
            str =  str.replace("J", "1");
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not agree with your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map your alphabet to digits as @Tim already showed using the letters as key and digits as values, check for negativity using regex and finaly replace map keys contained in input string with map values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(convert("45{"));
    System.out.println(convert("45A"));
    System.out.println(convert("45B"));
    System.out.println(convert("45}"));
    System.out.println(convert("45J"));
    System.out.println(convert("45K"));
}
public static long convert(String str){
    String alphabet = "{ABCDEFGHI}JKLMNOPQR";
    Map<String,String> map = Pattern.compile("")
                              .splitAsStream(alphabet)
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, k->String.valueOf(alphabet.indexOf(k)%10)));
    boolean isNegative = false;
    if(Pattern.compile("[J-R\\}]+").matcher(str).find()){
        isNegative = true;
    }
    for(String letter : alphabet.split("")){
        str = str.replace(letter, map.get(letter));
    }
    long result = Long.parseLong(str);
    return isNegative ? - result: result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.This resolves my problem. But a new problem is that, I am suggested by project team to use javascript instead of java. Can you suggest me how the same can be achieved in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

We can try iterating over the string, and then use the modulus to compute the numerical value:

```
String input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
    sb.append(String.valueOf((input.charAt(i) - 'A') % 10));
}

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(sb.toString());

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
012345678901234567
```

My output does line up exactly with what you have in your question, but your question appears to have some typos in the letter strings.

Comment: `sb.append(String.valueOf(x))` is the same as `sb.append(x)`, and `System.out.println(sb.toString())` is the same as `System.out.println(sb)` You can also detect if the result should be negative with `neg |= input.charAt(i) >= 'J'` Note: You assume there is no digits already.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Given that the scope of the OP is capital letters, I would presume just checking the input with a regex beforehand to make sure it does not have unexpected characters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -thanks for your reply. Well my expectation is to replace a particular character of string to corresponding digit.
for example:

45{ = 450 (as '{' represents positive '0' )

45A = 451 (as 'A' represents positive '1' )

45B = 452 (as 'A' represents positive '2' )

45}  = -450 (as '}' represents negative '0' )

45J  = -451 (as 'J' represents negative '1' )



45K  = -452 (as 'K' represents negative '2' )

Comment: OK, but do you realize that this is not at all what your question asked.  If you intended to ask something else, then edit your question, but in general you should not radically change a question after others have already answered.

Comment: Apologies. I have corrected the question to give an better idea of my expectation.